# Share plain text (not a link) to Facebook Messenger in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, share, facebook-messenger

I have found ways to share links using FBSDKShareKit. But I want to share plain text only and not a link. [contentDescription](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareLinkContent) and [contentTitle](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareLinkContent) have been deprecated. Only text can be shared through UIActivityController but it is not what I want.
It can be done in Whatsapp using ***whatsapp://send?text=message***, is there something along the similar lines for Facebook Messenger?

Comment: Try using `let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()`, set quote to `content`( not `contentURL`) and then show `FBSDKMessageDialog()`.

Comment: Can't set nil to contentURL. Error log : _FBSDKLog: The values in the parameters dictionary must be NSStrings or NSNumbers, '<null>' is not._ @AnkitJayaswal

Comment: Try not set anything or set empty string `""`.

Comment: Did you find the solution for same?